# Примером вашим будем жить

Tags: грамотная-речь

Хотел написать в стихотворении: "Примером вашим будем жить" , но засомневался. Понятно ли, что имеется в виду "Вы будете всегда нашим примером" , а не наоборот?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***"Примером вашим будем жить"***. Фраза воспринимается так: будем брать в пример какой-то ваш поступок, и этот поступок нас будет вдохновлять, подпитывать...

Вы правы: лучше изменить строчку стихотворения, чтобы смысл высказывания был точным - таким, какой нужен Вам.

Answer (score 0):

В целом согласен с Екатериной, но поскольку речь идёт о стихотворении, то ради рифмы и ритма эту строчку можно оставить - она передаёт смысл достаточно близко к желаемому.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Примером вашим будем жить - фраза не очень удачная.

ЖИТЬ 2. кем-чем. Б**ыть поглощённым чем-л., увлечённым кем-, чем-л., считать что-л. главным в жизни.** Ж. детьми, сыном, семьёй. Ж. наукой, театром, спортом Ж. какой-л. надеждой, ожиданием чего-л., воспоминаниями.

Из словаря видно, что можно жить воспоминаниями о ком-то, но это крайний случай. Память о других людях, примеры других людей обычно помогает нам жить, но не становятся самоцелью.

Да и слова "примером", "жить" обычно используются в сочетаниях другой тематики, например: Своим примером мы учим жить молодых.